# sql syntax for creating a new table out of multiple large tables

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I am new to MySql and sql. 
i can't figure out how to do the following:

i have a bus schedule database with four relevant *tables*:

```
stops (24,403 rows)
-------------------
stop_id   int(11)


stopTimes (12,073,459 rows)
---------------------------
trip_id         varchar(30)
stop_sequence   int(11)     // running sequence within the trip: 1-last
stop_id         int(11)

trips (320,395 rows) 
---------------------------
trip_id   varchar(30)
route_id  int(11)


routes (9,748 rows)
---------------------------
route_id            int(11)
agency_id           int(11)                     
route_short_name    varchar(10)
```

**relations**

- **routes to trips:** one to many
- **trips to stopTimes:** one to many
- **stops to stopTimes:** one to one

out of these tables i would like to create a new table "routeStops" with the following fields:

```
routeStops (~100,000 rows)
---------------------------
route_id            int(11)
agency_id           int(11)                     
route_short_name    varchar(10)
stop_id   int(11)
```

with a one to many relationship between it and the stops.

is there an **SQL query** that can perform that?

should i add an index  to the **route_id** and **stop_id** to optimize performance? should i add a fulltext index to trip_id?

i am new to that and will appreciate some insights.

i am using PHPMyAdmin and a rather new XAMPP installation.

tnx,

Comment: How is a table which has stop_id column suppose to have a one to many relationship with the stops ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is there an SQL query that can perform that?**

You can achieve it using the [INSERT ... SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO routeStops (route_id, agency_id, route_short_name, stop_id)
SELECT DISTINCT r.route_id, r.agency_id, r.route_short_name, s.stop_id
  FROM routes r
  JOIN trips t ON r.route_id = t.route_id
  JOIN stopTimes s ON t.trip_id = s.trip_id;
```

**Should I add an index to the route_id and stop_id to optimize performance?**

Those should be the primary key in their tables, and a foreign key in the other tables.

**Should I add a fulltext index to trip_id?**

I don't recommend it because it would be too slow. I suggest that you alter your tables and use an `int` for the trip_id:

```
CREATE TABLE trips (
  trip_id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  trip_id_old varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  route_id int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (trip_id)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT r.route_id
     , r.agency_id 
     , r.route_short_name
     , s.stop_id
  FROM stopTimes s
  JOIN trips t
    ON t.trip_id = s.trip_id
  JOIN routes r
    ON r.route_id = t.route_id
 GROUP
    BY r.route_id
     , r.agency_id 
     , r.route_short_name
     , s.stop_id
 ORDER
    BY r.route_id
     , r.agency_id 
     , r.route_short_name
     , s.stop_id
```

NOTE: this will eliminate any "duplicate" rows; if you want the duplicates to be 
returned, then just remove the GROUP BY clause.

For best performance of this query, you'd probably want covering indexes which have these as leading columns in the index.

```
    ON route (route_id,agency_id,route_short_name)
    ON stopTimes (trip_id, stop_id)
    ON trips (route_id, trip_id)
```